# Routes issue with Rails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, wso2

I'm working on getting WSO2 working on Windows with Rails using the following guide:

http://wso2.org/project/wsf/ruby/1.1.0/docs/install_guide.html

I've followed the instructions and I'm now trying to run the sample service "security".  The documentation specifies:

```
1. Copy security/security_controller.rb into the controllers directory of your rail application
2. Copy keys and policies directories into the controllers directory of your rail application
3. Try the services with your client using following endpoint addresses:
   http://your_rails_application_uri/security/callback
   http://your_rails_application_uri/security/timestamp
   http://your_rails_application_uri/security/timestamp_file
   http://your_rails_application_uri/security/usernametoken
   http://your_rails_application_uri/security/usernametoken_file
   http://your_rails_application_uri/security/signing
   http://your_rails_application_uri/security/signing_file
   http://your_rails_application_uri/security/encryption
   http://your_rails_application_uri/security/encryption_file
   http://your_rails_application_uri/security/complete
```

However when I type http://localhost:3000/timestamp, I get a routing error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/security/timestamp"
```

I'm trying to verify that the WSO2 framework has installed successfully.  I'm new to ruby and web services so I'm probably overlooking something trivial... any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Benjamin - thanks for the response.  rake routes doesn't return anything.  Routes.rb is all commented out as well.  Think this is related to the issue?  The instructions didn't mention anything about routes so I haven't touched them.